# google cloud storage verify

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

some way to verify that a file has been successfully uploaded to Google storage? I checked de documentation saw this function [gsutil hash](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/hash) but doesn't work.

```
   rvalenmo@arkham-asylum /tmp $ gsutil hash -m gs://sample/file_sample.csv
Hashes [base64] for file_sample.csv:
    Hash (crc32c):      dF6VGw==
    Hash (md5):     2/MHXvQnmk0vJb3CVLKEIA==

rvalenmo@arkham-asylum /tmp $ md5sum file_sample.csv
dbf3075ef4279a4d2f25bdc254b28420  file_sample.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to pass the `-h` option to `gsutil hash` so you can get a hex output instead of the default base64.  According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/hash):

> `-h`     Output hashes in hex format. By default, gsutil uses base64.

Comment: Hi Doug Thanks for the reply but no work it the same problem.

Comment: @sowe If you do `gsutil hash -m -h gs://sample/file_sample.csv` you shold get `dbf3075ef4279a4d2f25bdc254b28420` as hash, the same output as md5sum. Does that not answer your question?